# Search for multiple strings using 'class' at python

Tags: python

I have this code, that finds the word |1234| and copy all lines until abcd| is found, it doesn´t copy the line that contains abcd|.

I wanna make this code works with multiple strings. For example, search if the line contains |1234| or |56789| or |54321| and copy all the lines that have those words until the line abcd| (that doesn´t change).  By the way, the code also join all the txt into one ( I need to search at multiple files.
Is it possible to modify the code so it can search for multiple start_marker? How? Can anyone help me?

```
import glob
import os
class Collector:
    def __init__(self, filename, start_marker, stop_marker):
        self.toggle_collect = False
        self.f = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
        self.m1 = '|1234|'
        lf.m2 = 'abcd|'

    def __enter__ (self):
        return self

    def __exit__ (self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.f.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            r = next(self.f)
            if self.m1 in r:  # found the start-collecting marker
                self.toggle_collect = True
            elif self.m2 in r:  # found the stop-collecting marker
                self.toggle_collect = False
                continue
            if self.toggle_collect:  # we are collecting
                return r  # .rstrip()  # provide row


src_path = "e:/teste/Filtrados/"
dst_path = "e:/teste/FiltradosFinal/"
filelist = (fn for fn in os.listdir(src_path) if fn.endswith(".txt"))
for x in filelist:
    print(f"Processing file {x}")
    with open(os.path.join(dst_path, x), 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f, \
         Collector(os.path.join(src_path, x), '1234', 'abcd') as c:
        for r in c:
            f.write(r)

read_files = glob.glob("e:/teste/FiltradosFinal//*.txt")
with open("e:/teste/teste.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        print("Combinando arquivos")
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
```

INPUT

```
00000|12333|
something
word
another_one
abcd|
00000|12320|
something
word
another_one
abcd|
00000|12321|
something
word
another_one
abcd|
```

output

```
00000|12333|
something
word
another_one
abcd|
00000|12321|
something
word
another_one
abcd|
```

I wanna copy all, for example, the lines between '|12333|' or '|12321|' until the end mark is found abcd|. My code does that, but only if I set one mark, I wanna multiples start marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
import os


class Collector:
    def __init__(self, filename, start_marker, stop_marker):
        self.toggle_collect = False
        self.f = open(filename, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
        self.m1s = ['|1234|', 'other_word1', 'other_word2']
        self.m2 = 'abcd|'

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.f.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self



    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            r = next(self.f)
            for m1 in self.m1s:
                if self.m2 in r:  # found the stop-collecting marker
                   break
                if m1 in r:  # found the start-collecting marker
                   return r  # .rstrip()  # provide row



src_path = "e:/teste/Filtrados/"
dst_path = "e:/teste/FiltradosFinal/"
filelist = (fn for fn in os.listdir(src_path) if fn.endswith(".txt"))
for x in filelist:
    print(f"Processing file {x}")
    with open(os.path.join(dst_path, x), 'w', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f, \
            Collector(os.path.join(src_path, x), '1234', 'abcd') as c:
        for r in c:
            f.write(r)

read_files = glob.glob("e:/teste/FiltradosFinal//*.txt")
with open("e:/teste/teste.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        print("Combinando arquivos")
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
```

I did not test the code, as you didn't provide any convenient input or desired output, but this seems to do what you want.

I suggest using meaningful names rather than `m1` and `m2`, so you will be able to debug your own code when it becomes larger (let alone allow anyone else to read it).

Comment: I will add intput and desire output, your code is copying only the line that have the start mark and I wanna copy all lines until the mark is found

Comment: I think I made it work, I will test it later and accept your answer. Thanks!